# JavaScript disabled = true vs ASP.NET Enabled = False

Tags: javascript, asp.net, markup

In my ASP.NET web application, I have some elements that may be disabled in code-behind and some elements may be disabled in JavaScript.

For the code-behind elements, I simply use the following VB.NET property:

```
Me.element1.Enabled = False
```

For the dynamic elements, I use the following JavaScript property:

```
document.getElementById('" & Me.element2.ClientID & "').disabled = true;
```

The first thing I noticed is that changing the Enabled property doesn't just add `disabled="disabled"` to the markup, it also changes the class from `button` (my skinned class name for buttons) to `button aspNetDisabled`.  To compensate for this, I include the following additional JavaScript line:

```
document.getElementById('" & Me.element2.ClientID & "').className = 'button aspNetDisabled';
```

(Clearly, this means I need to maintain the className attribute if/when I enable the element again, and I'll need to ensure I use `button`/`textbox`/etc. as applicable - For bonus points, if you have any recommendations about this, I'd be happy to hear them)

**However, I also noticed that the markup produced via JavaScript is only `disabled=""`, whereas the markup produced by the ASP.NET Enabled property change is `disabled="disabled"`.**

I tried fiddling with the JavaScript to change it to:

```
document.getElementById('" & Me.element2.ClientID & "').disabled = 'disabled';
```

However, this didn't seem to make a difference, with the attribute still being empty.  Interesting that `disabled=true;` and `disabled='disabled';` seem to work in the same way - I expect one of them is more correct (I'm sticking to `=true;` for now).

**Is there a recommended best way of achieving the same results with JavaScript as with server-side ASP.NET with regards to enabling and disabling elements?**

and...

**Is the difference between the rendering of `disabled="disabled"` and `disabled=""` likely to cause me any problems?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `disabled` property doesn't matter, it is *implied* http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1

There is some strangeness going on though.

```
var my_elem = document.getElementById('my_elem');
elem.disabled = true;  // disabled
elem.disabled = false;  // enabled
elem.disabled = "false"; // disabled
```

The strange case is

```
elem.disabled = ""; // disabled
```

Normally `""` is *falsy* (as in `"" == false` is `true`).

I would recommend you use a framework to set these properties to catch any browser specific behavior. For `disabled` there isn't much strife but properties like `opacity` don't work the same in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The disabled attribute doesn't have to have a fixed value - it used to work without ANY value (e.g. `<input type=text disabled>`) but this caused some validation problems.  If you're already using jquery in your project, you can use something like:

```
$('#elementname').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('aspNetDisabled');  // Enable
```

and

```
$('#elementname').attr('disabled').addClass('aspNetDisabled');  // Disable
```

The difference between `disabled="disabled"` and `disabled="true"` does not matter.