# Click on "enabled = false" checkbox(asp.net) via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox, controls

I want to make eneble asp.net control by click on it. Using java. I know there is `removeAttr('disabled','disabled')` but it isn't working at all. I also know by looking on  DevTools, that when i make asp.net control enabled=false, then control is being put in `<span disabled="disabled">MyControl</span>`. That make me think that, maybe I should make my control disabled in other way but I do not know how. I would be pleased if someone could show me a way to solve this problem or rather a direction witch I should head to solve by my efforts this problem.

Comment: java != javascript; just remember to clarify clearly. i'll come up with an answer quite soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [JavaScript disabled = true vs ASP.NET Enabled = False](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11931762/1456376)?

Comment: Regarding you saying: "*[…] it isn't working at all*" it's hard to guess. Please add the relevant JavaScript parts to your question. Maybe your selector is wrong, or you're missing to place your script at the end of the body or you don't call it on DOM ready … There are too many possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for it is to make a div on that checkbox who will disapear when clicked and it will

```
removeAttr('disabled','disabled')
```

Although you have to make a function that will detect at begin which checkbox should be covered by div and disabled

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to set "enabled = false" (which appears to be what you wanted in your title; i didn't understand what you wanted to say in your question...):

```
attr('enabled', 'false');
```

And for "disabled = true":

```
attr('disabled', 'true');
```

Hope this is what you wanted.

UPDATE: Looking at the comment underneath, here's my new answer.

First, assign an ID:

```
<span id="control" disabled="disabled">MyControl</span>
```

Then, have an `.click` event from jquery:

```
control = $("#control")
contorl.click(function() {
    control.attr('disabled', 'false');
});
```

Comment: The questioner wants to re-enable a disabled `<span>` element by clicking on the disabled element itself - at least that's how I read it.

Comment: Are you answering to confuse OP `$(".control")` refers to element with class `control` not `id`.For id --> `$("#control")` and disabled element can not be clicked .

Answer (score 0):

Sample html

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="text" />
</div>
```

It's kind of difficult to understand what you are asking. I think you are asking one of the following:

Scenario A : You want to click on a checkbox and make another element enabled/disabled.

```
$("#check").click(function(){
    var text = $("#text");
    if(text.is(":disabled")){
        text.prop("disabled", false );
    }
    else{
        text.prop("disabled", true );
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nxEEv/)

Scenario B: You want to click on a checkbox and toggle it's own disabled state.

This would not make any sense because when the checkbox is not checked it is kind of disabled. Also, you cannot capture click events on a disabled element.